# How to add workflow task's "Edit task" button (or link) in a workflow email?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have a workflow designed for calendar events. As soon as the user adds an item, I initiate the workflow to send an email to the manager for approval.

For example (I edit the workflow in SP designer for customized email message),

```
Dear Manager,

Please approve the following event: Event details
```

(FYI I already implemented it, but I am not sure how to do the next step).

```
Please approve by clicking the link ["Approve/Reject"][1]
```

--- Now this will directly go to the following window (workflow task edit)

[image]

When I searched for answer, people were telling to add workflow task list's "Edit task" button (or link) in email. But How can I add this button (or link) in email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SharePoint Designer to build the workflow, you most likely have created a Task process for which you could use `[%Current Task:Form_URN%]`

Comment: Worked perfectly. The dates are displayed weird. I use [%Current List:End Date%] but it displays  Monday, January 01, 0001. List is a calendar here. May I know how to solve it?

Comment: You could rely on formatting functions http://blogs.3sharp.com/2009/01/28/modifying-date-formats-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/